# angularjs undefined $scope array object parameter

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object

Let see my Angularjs code:

My function 'getequipselected' from my 'EmpApi' factory request data of my webservice and save it in response:

```
EmpApi.getequipselected(idequip).success(function (response) {
            $scope.editequipamento = response;

            console.log(response);
```

Its perfectly working, it printed on console log browser: Array [ Object ]

If a click on 'Objetc', I can see all parameters: idEquipamento, TAG, idDiretoria, idFabricante ...

So i trieded to print the $scope:

```
console.log($scope.editequipamento);
```

I printed it to check, it was the same of console.log(response)

**The problem is here: I tried to print it:**

```
console.log($scope.editequipamento.TAG);
```

I tried to print one parameter from object but in gave me 'undefined'

I trieded it because I'd like to pass this value to my html input, using `ng-model="editequipamento.TAG",` but the input is also undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `editequipamento[0].TAG`.  I think your object is inside of array of list.

You need to use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), if you have bulk array

Comment: Yes, but if you need pass multiple array object, then you need use `ng-repeat` for bind the record as table format

Comment: Perfect! It worked! Só, if a like to pass it to my html input can I do this:

$scope.editequipamento[0] = $scope.equip

So, use console.log(equip.TAG) ?

Comment: I just have one object in this array, how can I create a object in order to a array for this response?

Comment: please ask a new question fro more details

Answer (score 1):

the response was array not an object so u have to access the first object of that array.

```
console.log($scope.editequipamento[0].TAG);
```